# Patched Binary does not open

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

I'm newbie in Reverse Engineering and I'm trying to change a jnz condition to jz with IDA. After I patched the binary the application can not be open.

There's the original binary:

[image]

And the modified:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Another hypothesis for the problem is that the patched binary has a different number of bytes due to the switch from jnz to jz. Can be it? If so, how can I resolve this difference in bytes?

Comment: Do you get any error?  Can you diff both binaries? What is the result?

Comment: Can you provide the patched binary?

Comment: From the description it sounds like there was no underlying reason for the change. You just wanted to change `jnz` to `jz`. Sometimes the program might work sometimes it might not. What you wanted to achieve with this change?

Comment: the program has a 10 second delay. This jnz checks if the counter has already reached zero to start the program. Another hypothesis for the problem is that the patched binary has a different number of bytes due to the switch from jnz to jz. Can be it? If so, how can I resolve this difference in bytes?

Comment: What tool did you use to patch the actual binary? You should only have changed a single byte for a short jump, i.e. `75` (JNZ) to `74` (JZ).

Comment: @fpmurphy I did use IDA Pro. I selected the jnz instruction and edit -> Assemble. Then, Edit-> generate patch binary.

Answer (score 0):

JZ and JNZ both have 1 or 2 byte instructions not including arguments.  Perhaps IDA used a different sized instruction.

To view the assembly bytes to go Options->General->Disassembly and in "Number of Opcode bytes" put an 8.  Now you can see the bytes in the disassembly.

Now you can change back and forth and find out how many bytes each instruction is.

View more info about these instructions [here](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc)

If IDA is generating the wrong instruction, then manually change it by editing the hex.

You can always view file size to see if the size has changed.  If the program continues to "not run", attach the debugger and find out why, there is no reason I can think of, if the number of bytes is the same it should work fine with the worst case scenario being an infinite loop